# Dúvida sobre Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, post

Fiz um custom post type para WordPress, mas na hora de mostrar os posts na categoria não funciona. Se eu entrar no URL `example.com/category/mensagem-02/`, não aparece nada.

Alguém pode me ajudar? O código que usei.

```php
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type_mensagem() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Mensagens', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Mensagem', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Mensagem', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'Todos os Post', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Adicionar Novo Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Adicionar Novo', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'mensagem',
    'with_front'          => false,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'mensagem', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Blog de mensagens', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array(  'category', 'post_tag','link_category' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'mensagem', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_mensagem', 0 );
```

Comment: Não entendo... você tem uma categoria que se chama `mensagem-02`?

Comment: Sim, fiz como teste. 
Mas qualquer categoria que crio para o custom post type não aparece nada.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você não entendeu bem o conceito de Custom Post Type - CPT. Um CPT é um tipo personalizado de post e apesar dele poder ter suas prórias categorias¹ um CPT não é uma categoria e em sua forma padrão você não terá acesso através da URL mencionada.

Para exibir os posts deste CPT que você criou a URL seria `www.seusite.com/mensagem` e o arquivo de maior hierarquia é o archive-mensagem.php. Crie esse arquivo, acesse o menu `Configurações > Links permanentes` e click em salvar, depois acesse a URL como falei acima e, se seu arquivo `archive-mensagem.php` estiver correto, os posts do CPT mensagem vão aparecer.

---

1 -Na real são chamadas de taxonomy, mas mantive categoria pra facilitar o entendimento

Answer (score 1):

Conseguir fazer o que queria adicionando este codigo:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'your-custom-post-type-here'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Comment: Como esse código resolveu o problema? Você poderia explicar onde colocou ele, e com que propósito? Assim mais gente pode aprende como você resolveu.